# Fuzzy name matching for identity resolution with zentity.io

Tags: elasticsearch

Using the zentity.io plugin for entity resolution, I've tried to design an entity model that allows me to look for entities (in this case people) with a single search string (presumable a full name).

```
POST _zentity/models/person
{
"attributes": {
  "first_name": {
    "type": "string"
  },
   "middle_name": {
    "type": "string"
  },
   "last_name": {
    "type": "string"
  }
},
"resolvers": {
  "full_name": {
    "attributes" : ["first_name", "middle_name", "last_name"]
  },
  "first_and_last": {
    "attributes" : ["first_name", "last_name"]
  },
  "middle_and_last" : {
    "attributes" : ["middle_name", "last_name"]
  }
},
"matchers": {
  "exact": {
    "clause": {
      "term": {
        "{{ field }}": "{{ value }}"
      }
    }
  },
  "fuzzy": {
    "clause": {
      "match": {
        "{{ field }}": {
          "query": "{{ value }}",
          "fuzziness": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
"indices": {
  "my-index": {
    "fields": {
      "firstName": {
        "attribute": "first_name",
        "matcher": "fuzzy"
      },
      "middleName": {
        "attribute": "middle_name",
        "matcher": "fuzzy"
      },
      "surname": {
        "attribute": "last_name",
        "matcher": "fuzzy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I defined my attributes of the entity resolution model (i.e. first_name, middle_name and last_name), defined the matchers for the attributes (in this case only the fuzzy matcher is used) and defined several resolvers that explain which combination of matching attributes result in a matching entity.

So I would for example have an entity with attributes like this:

```
{
  "first_name": "Edgar",
  "middle_name": "Allan",
  "last_name": "Poe"
}
```

And searching with the following query would result in a match, according to my **middle_and_last** resolver.

```
POST _zentity/resolution/person?pretty
{
  "attributes": {
    "middle_name": ["Allan"],
    "last_name": ["Poe"]
  }
}
```

**However**, the search string that I use for searching is unstructured. Meaning that I have to search with something like "Poe Edgar Allan", a full name that potentially has a different order than what you'd expect. And it's just one string. No way to tell what the first, middle or last name is.

How do I adjust my model to make sure that, regardless of the input string (Edgar Allan Poe, Poe Edgar Allan, Edgar Poe, Poe Allan, etc.) I am still able to find a match according to what my resolvers describe as one? Not knowing what is the last name, middle name or first name.